# Does SPDC (spontaneous parametric down-conversion) type used depend on design of individual quantum erasure experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What is the type of spontaneous parametric down-conversion (SPDC) used in the following quantum eraser experiment?

One of the facts that need clarification is whether the generation of entangled photons implicitly means that such an experiment must use type-II SPDC BBO crystal or whether the design of the experiment allows freedom of choosing between type-I and type-II.

Source: [Wikipedia: Quantum eraser experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment)

> First, a photon is shot through a specialized nonlinear optical
> device: a beta barium borate (BBO) crystal. This crystal converts the
> single photon into two entangled photons of lower frequency, a process
> known as spontaneous parametric down-conversion (SPDC). These
> entangled photons follow separate paths. One photon goes directly to a
> polarization-resolving detector, while the second photon passes
> through the double-slit mask to a second polarization-resolving
> detector. Both detectors are connected to a coincidence circuit,
> ensuring that only entangled photon pairs are counted. A stepper motor
> moves the second detector to scan across the target area, producing an
> intensity map. This configuration yields the familiar interference
> pattern.
>
> Next, a circular polarizer is placed in
> front of each slit in the double-slit mask, producing clockwise
> circular polarization in light passing through one slit, and
> counter-clockwise circular polarization in the other slit (see Figure
> 1). (Which slit corresponds to which polarization depends on the
> polarization reported by the first detector.) This polarization is
> measured at the second detector, thus "marking" the photons and
> destroying the interference pattern (see Fresnel–Arago laws).
>
> Finally, a linear polarizer is introduced in the path of the first
> photon of the entangled pair, giving this photon a diagonal
> polarization (see Figure 2). Entanglement ensures a complementary
> diagonal polarization in its partner, which passes through the
> double-slit mask. This alters the effect of the circular polarizers:
> each will produce a mix of clockwise and counter-clockwise polarized
> light. Thus the second detector can no longer determine which path was
> taken, and the interference fringes are restored.
>
> A double slit with rotating polarizers can also be accounted for by
> considering the light to be a classical wave. However, this
> experiment uses entangled photons, which are not compatible with
> classical mechanics.

---

- Figure 1. Crossed polarizations prevent interference fringes
  [image: Figure 1]

---

---

- Figure 2. Introduction of polarizer in upper path restores interference fringes below

[image: Figure 2]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular requirement that Type II BBo crystals must be used for a quantum eraser experiment.  As you mention, Type II is used in your reference (see link to full paper below).  The choice is really one of convenience, quality of entangled photon source, etc.  You can actually shift (rotate) the polarization by suitable use of wave plates anyway, although there is no real purpose to doing so.

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0106078